# Rebuild boost-thread package with vcpkg without redownload

Tags: c++, boost, vcpkg

I use vcpkg as a package manager for my c++ projects I develop in Visual Studio 2017. I need to make some changes to one of the boost-thread library .cpp files so that it can work with my project.

How can I rebuild (or reinstall) only this boost-thread library so that my changes are taking into account (without that vcpkg redownloads the boost-thread from the web).

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance,